# iwconfig does not show Noise Level for wireless

Tags: linux, wireless, noise

I have a Dell Latitude E6410, which uses an Intel Ultimate N-6300 Wireless card. iwconfig does not show the Noise level of the wireless interface , wlan0. Does anyone know the reason for that?

```
precise@ubuntu:~/Desktop/Work/transmitter$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

mon0      IEEE 802.11abgn  Mode:Monitor  Tx-Power=15 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          
wlan0     IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:"AirPennNet"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: D8:C7:C8:D7:A6:C1   
          Bit Rate=130 Mb/s   Tx-Power=15 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=65/70  Signal level=-45 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:800  Invalid misc:540   Missed beacon:0

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

I tried to use cat /proc/net/wireless and got these results

```
Inter-| sta-|   Quality        |   Discarded packets               | Missed | WE
 face | tus | link level noise |  nwid  crypt   frag  retry   misc | beacon | 22
 wlan0: 0000   64.  -46.  -256        0      0      0    818    566        0
```

Is -256 the noise level? How do i interpret this in dBm?

Comment: I'm having a similar issue with my Asus G51J with an Atheros Communications Inc. AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (using ath9k)

I'm also seeing -256 as the noise level so I'm guessing this means there is no measurement available. I'm also curious as to why this is.

Comment: I believe the `Quality / noise` value to be broken. I have seen the value be invariably `-256` in many different systems.

Answer (score 1):

The answer lies within your driver and wireless card support.

I have a similar Dell Latitude model but with an Intel(R) Centrino(R) Advanced-N 6200 AGN wireless card. After issuing the `iwconfig` command, the output also revealed something similar - the `Noise` parameter was missing (this was done while in connection to an access point, of course).

Not happy with that, I got out another wireless card (Winstron NeWeb AR9170+AR9104 802.11abgn - basically a Proxim Wireless 802.11a/b/g/n Wi-Fi USB dongle) and issued the same command. The output was still the same, the `Noise` parameter was not there!

This wasn't what I had expected since I knew very well that we had used the same Wi-Fi dongle to detect the noise level associated with access points using a proprietary software by Fluke Network called the AirMagnet WiFi Analyzer PRO. I even tried downloading and re-compiling the Linux Wireless Tools package from Jean Tourrilhes' but similar output was shown as before.

The next step I did was to verify again that the WiFi dongle actually *does* show the WiFi noise levels under the AirMagnet WiFi Analyzer software. Sure enough, it does (as depicted in the attached image below).

[image: WiFi Noise levels using USB dongle]

The blue column with the header 'N' refers to the noise level. Mind you, the WiFi dongle also came along with a proprietary driver when we bought the AirMagnet software along with it.

Having done that, I decided to see what it would show for our internal WiFi card (Intel(R) Centrino(R) Advanced-N 6200 AGN). Here are the results:

[image: WiFi Noise levels using Intel Centrino Advanced-N 6200 AGN]

All of them are displaying values of -100! So, I believe it all has something to do with the driver/card capabilities.